# Getting JS to open a particular tab <div> on a page 2 using #anchor from link on page 1

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, tabs, anchor

I have a menu as follow on a particular page 1:

```
    <li class="menu3"><a href="#">Our expertise</a>
    <div class="sub-expertise">
         <ul>
             <li><a href="page2.html#what1">one</a></li>
             <li><a href="page2.html#what2">two</a></li>
             <li><a href="page2.html#what3">three</a></li>
             <li><a href="page2.html#what4">four</a></li>
         </ul>
       </div>
    </li>
```

On the other page (page 2), a js controls which tab is open:

```
`<div class="center" id="tabs">     
<ul class="what_list">                  
<li><a href="#what1">one</a></li>                   
<li><a href="#what2">two</a></li>                         
<li><a href="#what3">three</a></li>                         
<li><a href="#what4">four</a></li>                 
</ul>                 
<div id="what1"></div>                  
<div id="what2"></div>                  
<div id="what3"></div>                  
<div id="what4"></div>        
</div>`
```

I would like the link on page 1 to open a particular sections elected (what1, etc...) on page 2:
Currently on page 2, I have a js that allow to open and close each section using the id="tabs" as follow:

```
  `  <script>

jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    /* opening/closing of the menu*/ 
      
    <!-- tab function 
    $('#tabs div').hide();
        $('#tabs div:first').show();
        $('#tabs ul li:first').addClass('active');
    
        $('#tabs ul li a').click(function(){
            $('#tabs ul li').removeClass('active');
            $(this).parent().addClass('active');
            var currentTab = $(this).attr('href');
            $('#tabs div').hide();
            $(currentTab).show();
            return false;
        }); 

      });
      </script>`
```

I tried adding the #anchor to the link as follow but it doesn't work, I think because of the js that already controls the tab open and close on page 2.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is below, with explanatory comments in the code (CSS and JavaScript); please note that I did update the HTML, adding a `class="tab"` to each of the elements that serve as tabs, and I added dummy content to allow those elements to be differentiated. The class is required for the functionality, the content can be changed as required):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    // here we retrieve the current fragment-identifier, the 'hash':
    let hash = document.location.hash;
  
  /* if there is no hash, or if the hash - after removing leading/trailing white-
     space - has a length equal to zero: */
  if (!hash || 0 === hash.trim().length) {
    // we set the document's hash to be equal to:
        // the id of the first .tab element which is the first of its type
      // (based on its element-type, not the class-name) that has an 'id'
      // attribute, and we retrieve the id; we use a template literal to
      // interpolate that value with the preceding '#' character,
      // and that then allows CSS to handle showing the relevant element:
    document.location.hash = `#${$('.tab[id]:first-of-type').prop('id')}`;
  }
});
```

```css
:root {
  --color1: rgb(208 223 240 / 0.5);
  --color2: rgb(255 255 200 / 0.7);
}

/* The numbered (1. and 2.) comments below (at the end of the CSS)
   explain how the CSS handles the tab show/hide functionality */


/* a simple reset to remove default margins and padding from
   elements, and applying the border-box algorithm for sizing
   which includes any padding and border-widths in the
   declared sizes of an element: */
*, ::before, ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* setting the base font for the document: */
body {
  font-family: system-ui;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

h2, p {
  background-color: transparent;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: 700;
}

ul, li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.center {
  block-size: 80vh;
  display: grid;
  gap: 1rem;
  grid-template-rows: 4rem 1fr;
  inline-size: clamp(20rem, 80%, 1100px);
  margin-inline: auto;
}

.center ul {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
  grid-row: 1;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

li {
  border: 1px solid currentColor;
  display: grid;
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: center;
  padding-block: 0.25em;
  padding-inline: 0.5em;
}

/* to have the <a> fill the space of its wrapper: */
li > a {
  flex-grow: 1;
}


/* 1.
-------------------------------
First, hide the tab elements (.tab):
*/
.tab {
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 25% 25%, var(--color1) 0%, var(--color2, yellow) 100%);
  display: none;
  /* placing all elements in the same grid-column
     and the same grid-row (I'm using CSS grid,
     your own implementation may be different);
     I'm specifying both row and column to prevent
     the browser creating an implicit grid to
     show all content in its own row/column: */
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 2;
}

/* 2.
-------------------------------
Second, show the relevant tab element, using the :target
pseudo-class::
*/
.tab:target {
  display: block;
}

#what1 {
  --color2: rgb(238 230 100 / 1);
}

#what2 {
  --color2: rgb(0 255 0 / 1);
}

#what3 {
  --color2: rgb(0 0 255 / 1);
}

#what4 {
  --color2: rgb(255 0 255 / 1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="center" id="tabs">
  <ul class="what_list">
    <li><a href="#what1">one</a></li>
    <li><a href="#what2">two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#what3">three</a></li>
    <li><a href="#what4">four</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="what1" class="tab">
    <h2>One</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam a mollitia, nesciunt deserunt aliquam, molestiae saepe. Illo nam dolore similique?</p>
  </div>
  <div id="what2" class="tab">
    <h2>Two</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam a mollitia, nesciunt deserunt aliquam, molestiae saepe. Illo nam dolore similique?</p>
  </div>
  <div id="what3" class="tab">
    <h2>Three</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam a mollitia, nesciunt deserunt aliquam, molestiae saepe. Illo nam dolore similique?</p>
  </div>
  <div id="what4" class="tab">
    <h2>Four</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam a mollitia, nesciunt deserunt aliquam, molestiae saepe. Illo nam dolore similique?</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/hqfa1m39/1/).

References:

- CSS:

  - [`:target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target).
- JavaScript:

  - [`location.hash`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/hash).
  - [Template-literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Comment: It seems complicated to add the css to control the show and hide of each section.
The js I used already does that on the page in a simpler way.
Is there a way to modify the js (I am pretty novice to js) to add the document url hash checker so that it can update to open the desired tab?